# pagination with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to select the href links of all the schools from all pages. I did some python code and it worked for first page.

I want the script to print links of all the schools from all pages. currently it is printing for the first page

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

main_url = urlopen('https://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/football/1/state/florida.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_url,'lxml')
pages = soup.find('ol',{'class':'pagination btn-bar'})
#
for page in pages:
    url = requests.get('https://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/football/{}/state/florida.htm'.format(page)).text
    sou = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
    My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'mx-grid sortable rankings-grid'})
    links = My_table.findAll('a')
    print(links)
```

Comment: Apparently, check ``sou = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')``, I think you wrote it wrong, shouldn't it be ``soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')``?

Comment: that's working fine I want help with pagination

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number of pages from the pagination then do a loop to collect all.

Pagination ordered list:

[image]

If you look at the above you can see there is a pagination ordered list (`ol`) element with class 'pagination btn-bar'; I can, in this case, use a [css class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to isolate this element by passing a single class value from the multi-value pair i.e. `.pagination`. This gets me the parent `ol` element. I then add in a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) and `a` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) meaning I want to select all the child `a` tags within this `ol` class matched parent.  `soup.select('.pagination a')` returns me a list of all these children - the pagination you can see bottom left in image 1,2,3,.....->. The total number of pages is given by the penultimate `a` tag i.e. 7; so, I can use list indexing to retrieve this item from the list, access the `.text` property and convert to `int` so I can use in a loop over all pages.

```
int(soup.select('.pagination a')[-2].text)
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links = []

def get_links(r, links, first_link = False):
    soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
    if first_link:
        return int(soup.select('.pagination a')[-2].text)
    links+=[i['href'] if i['href'].startswith('http') else 'https://www.maxpreps.com' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=high-schools]')]

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/football/1/state/florida.htm')
    pages = get_links(r, links, True)

    for page in range(2, pages+1):
        get_links(s.get(f'https://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/football/{page}/state/florida.htm'), links)
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in web scraping can you please explain what you dd

Comment: Added some more info for you.